# Why does this program return a list of atoms?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So I am learning Lisp at school and one of the programs I have to create is one that duplicates the functionality of remove-if-not by using mapcan. I have created the program and it works correctly but I don't understand the output.

Specifically, if I were to run:

```
(findall 'numberp '(1 a 3))
```

The output is: (1 3)

The program is the following:

```
(defun findAll (fct l)
(cond
        ((null l) nil)
        ((mapcan (lambda(x) (if (funcall fct x) (list x) nil )) l))
    )
)
```

My understanding of the solution is the following:
"For each of the elements of the list l call the lambda function. If the result of the function fit and the element x returns true, then return the element surrounded by parentheses, otherwise return nil"

What specifically I am not understanding is how a series of consecutive calls to "list(x)" will in the end return a list of atoms such as (1 2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you have tagged your question SLIME, which is an IDE.

Let's format and indent your code readable.

```
(defun findAll (fct l)
  (cond
   ((null l) nil)
   ((mapcan (lambda (x)
              (if (funcall fct x)
                  (list x)
                nil))
            l))))
```

It's possible to write it that way, but usually we have a `T` condition to make clear that the last clause is always called.

```
(defun findAll (fct l)
  (cond
   ((null l) nil)
   (t (mapcan (lambda (x)
                (if (funcall fct x)
                    (list x)
                  nil))
              l))))
```

Since `MAPCAN` already deals with empty lists, you can just delete the `COND` and the first clause. `findAll` is typically named as `find-all`.

```
(defun find-all (fn list)
  (mapcan (lambda (item)
            (if (funcall fn item)
                (list item)
              nil))
          list))
```

> For each of the elements of the list l call the lambda function. If the result of the function fit and the element x returns true, then return the element surrounded by parentheses, otherwise return nil

For each of the elements of the list `LIST` call the lambda function. If the result of the function `FN` and the element `ITEM` returns true, then return a list of just the `ITEM`, otherwise return the empty list. The end result is the (destructively) appended list of all result lists of the lambda function.

Comment: But why is the end result appended together? Isn’t it just a bunch of lists?

Comment: @edoreld:MAPCAN does that. See its documentation: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcan